# Como puedo recorre una cadena en C# sin usar .Lenght?¿

Tags: c#

Quiero recorrer la variable string consonantes sin usar .Length

```
 //Recorrer las consonantes y recorrer la cadena y sumar al contador cada vez que aparezca una
            for (int j = 0; j < consonantes.Length; j++){
                for (int i = 0; i < cadena.Length; i++){
                    if (cadena[i] == consonantes[j]){
                        contadordeconsonantes++;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Por que motivo quieres hacer esto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

un bucle anidado siempre es una mala idea, debido a que aunque el nombre de la variable consonantes da a entender que se va a cruzar con las consonantes de nuestro idioma, esto no tiene que ser asi, o si se mete dentro de una funcion, se reutilice posteriormente. Un bucle anidado es una formula segura hacia una futura caida de rendimiento.

pongamos que le paso un texto de 500.000 y a consonantes le doy un valor de un texto de 100.000 caracteres, eso se va a eternizar

No digo que no se use, sino que cuando se use hay que intentar controlarlo con condiciones de salida (por ejemplo cuando ya haya comprobado que la letra esta dentro de consonantes, no hace falta seguir el for interno) y se puede salir del mismo.

yo haria algo mas en el sentido:

```
   foreach (var letra in cadena) 
   { 
      if (consonantes.Contains(letra)) contadordeconsonantes++;
   }
```

Notese que el método .Contains() enmascara un bucle interno también, pero tal y como esta implementado en c#, tiene incorporadas condiciones de salida y optimizaciones en la busqueda.

Comment: ¿Por qué un bucle anidado es mala idea? ¿Qué hace este código? Pulsa en [edit] y mejora tu respuesta. Lee [answer].

Comment: `Contains` es otro bucle, así que acabas teniendo un bucle anidado.

Comment: Ya lo se y si lees toda la respuesta encuentras la explicacion al final

Answer (score 1):

No se qué tiene de malo usar la propiedad `Length`, pero si tanta manía le tienes, puedes usar un bucle `foreach`:

```
foreach (var consonante in consonantes) {
    foreach (var letra in cadena) {
        if (letra == consonante) {
            ++contadordeconsonantes;
        }
    }
}
```